Liquibase is taking more time
We are using Liquibase for DB deploy and when ever we raise a PR we have ETL deploy workflow which uses Liquibase to deploy db change. Most of the time it will stuck in liquibase tag or liquibase running validation. Here is the Yaml code we are using
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance
Liquibase version : 4.24.0
Data warehosue: Redshift
set -e

ls -la

if [[ ${ROLLBACK} == "true" ]]; then
  export LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_TAG=$DB_VERSION
fi

echo "DB Deployment execution"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_SEARCH_PATH:                  $LIQUIBASE_SEARCH_PATH"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_URL:                  $LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_URL"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME:             $LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_CHANGELOG_FILE:       $LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_CHANGELOG_FILE"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_CONTEXTS:             $LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_CONTEXTS"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_LIQUIBASE_SCHEMA_NAME:        $LIQUIBASE_LIQUIBASE_SCHEMA_NAME"
echo "- LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DEFAULT_SCHEMA_NAME:  $LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_DEFAULT_SCHEMA_NAME"
echo "- DB_VERSION:                             $DB_VERSION"
echo "- DRY_RUN:                                $DRY_RUN"
echo "- ROLLBACK:                               $ROLLBACK"

echo "Running Validation =========================================================="
liquibase validate

echo "Checking Status =========================================================="
liquibase status --verbose

echo "Printing sqls ============================================================"
if [[ ${ROLLBACK} == "true" ]]; then
  liquibase rollback-sql
else
  liquibase update-sql
fi

if [[ ${DRY_RUN} == "true" ]]; then
  echo "Skipping deployment as the pipeline is triggered in dryrun mode =========="
  exit 0;
fi

if [[ ${ROLLBACK} == "true" ]]; then
  echo "Executing rollback =================================="
  liquibase rollback
else
  echo "Executing deployment =================================="
  liquibase update
  echo "Performing tagging ====================================================="  
  liquibase tag --tag=$DB_VERSION
fi

liquibase history




